# Review Audit Test failed - Why

Tags: discussion, review, review-audits

I just failed [this](https://superuser.com/review/first-answers/1103938) review audit, but I think that it probably is designed wrong as I wanted to Share Feedback that the answer needs supporting information, as there is no source linked to the claim the author makes. Shouldn't that be a valid option?

For me it is not important that the failed audit shows up in the history of me reviewing answers, but for others that just started to get into reviewing this could be misleading.

Comment: What would have been your feedback on that perfectly valid answer?

Comment: @Ramhound the usual „this answer could be improved with additional information and citation“ and so on

Comment: I always advise opening reviews in another tab and view the actual question.